# Mysql: where after having

Tags: mysql

I have the following posts table:

```
+-------------------+
|  name   |  type   |
+---------+---------+
| admin-1 |  type1  |
| user-1  |  type1  |
+-------------------+
```

I want to group the posts by type and return them if the group has more than 1 element, and then filter this result based on the name.

This is the query is tried:

```
select count(*), type from posts where name like 'admin-%' group by type having count(*) > 1
```

However in my query, `where` is executed "before" the `group by` clause, so I don't get `type1` in my result set.

How could I achieve what I want ?

Thanks

Comment: Leave out the where

Comment: I don't get your comment. Where do I put the 'where' then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nested queries

```
SELECT * FROM posts
WHERE type IN (
    SELECT type FROM posts GROUP BY type HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AND name LIKE 'admin-%'
```

Comment: This makes sense, but is it not possible to do it with a single select ?

Comment: @sroup nope, I don't this you can do it without nesting queries

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
select p.* 
from posts p
where p.name like 'admin-%'
and exists (select 1 from posts where type = p.type and name <> p.name)
```

If you expect only 1 row for each type in the results, then you can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
select type,
       max(case when name like 'admin-%' then name end) name 
from posts 
group by type 
having count(*) > 1 and sum(name like 'admin-%') > 0
```